# Android presents envelope-like placeholder character instead greek ς sigma letter

Tags: android, string, utf-8, character-encoding, char

I'm getting date formatted with:

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    ts,
    now.getTime(),
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
    DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

Device has Greek language set. In logcat the output is correct:

```
πριν από 2 ώρες
```

But device displays weird placeholder character for greek ς sigma letter:

[image]

Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: You mean Settings->Language & input? I have Greek set there (and that's why that string is in Greek which is what I want).

Comment: Looks like a font issue: the font used lacks a glyph for the final sigma (an envelope-like symbol is one of the common indicators for such problems), and it also has a poor implementation of acute accent / tonos on letters (the accent should apper at the vertical midline, not to the right of the character it is attached to).